# IOS: forcing update before app becomes visible

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a timer in my app, and I want it to appear to be running while my app is on the background. I'd like that if the user presses the home button when the timer shows, for instant "01:11:11" and then goes back to the app and it becomes visible to him 10 minutes later, to see the timer as "01:01:11", however I get a split second where it shows the last state when the app went to the background ("01:11:11") before it starts updating from the correct time.

I assumed that I could correct this by updating the state of my timer in "applicationDidBecomeActive" and it did work on my simulator in Xcode but not on my Ipad.

I'm using cocos2d for my drawing and this is what I'm doing in my applicationDidBecomeActive:

```
CCScene *s=[director_ runningScene];
GameLayer *l=[(GameLayer*)[s getChildByTag:GAME_LAYER_TAG];
if (l!=nil) [l myUpdate];
```

I don't think it's relevant to the problem though because myUpdate does get called but I still have that split second glitch on my Ipad, as if it starts back from its last state no matter what.

Comment: Doesn't iOS take cache a bitmap with the last graphics state of the app before backgrounding it and then use this immediately on resumption?

Comment: Yes Marko, you are correct. iOS takes a screenshot of the app before it goes in to the background. There's no way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In apples clock app, in applicationDidEnterBackground it hides the timer text, so that when the app comes into the foreground you see a blank UI for the split second where your app is loading the new timer data in the UI. Also, you may want to call some of your applicationDidBecomeActive code in applicationWillEnterForeground, which is called first. But keep in mind, applicationWillEnterForeground is **not** called when the app first launches.

There will always be a delay between when your app comes into the foreground, and when the UI updates. Theres no way to fix that, so you might as well use what apple uses to get around the issue.

Comment: I tried to hide my UI but I did it in my applicationWillResignActive, and so when I double clicked the home button it created an invisible preview, but doing that in applicationDidEnterBackground seems to do the trick, thanks.

Comment: Yeah applicationDidEnterBackground is called when the user can no longer see your app.

Comment: Well I checked again and at least on my ipad it doesn't work because the screen shot appears to be taken between applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground, which means that if I hide my UI in the first, it screws the preview (double click on the home button) and if I hide my UI in the second, it won't solve to my original problem :(

Comment: Actually it is taken even before applicationWillResignActive. I guess it's a non solvable.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried to hide my UI in both applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground. Since applicationWillResignActive is called first and before going into preview (double click on HOME) it causes a "not so pretty" preview but I thought at least it would solve my original problem. It didn't (not, on my IPad). It looks like the system takes the screen shot even before applicationWillResignActive.

I checked the timer in the official clock app and I see the clock is updating even when the app is in the background (in preview), so they "cheat" anyway...